# Error 400 with flask-login only in browser

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, http-error

I'm building a login for a web application using the framework flask and the extension flask-login. Using an HTTP client like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) to make http request to my api, everything work perfectly, but when I try it into the browser, it always return error 400. Here's the code:

```
@app.route('/api/protected')
@flask_login.login_required
def protected():
    #return flask_login.current_user.id + " is now logged in"
    return redirect('site-to-interface.html', code=302)


@app.route('/api/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    email = request.form['email']
    passwd = request.form['passwd']
    data = getUsersData()
    for key in data:
        if(email == data[key]["email"] and passwd == data[key]["pass"]):
            user = User()
            user.id = email
            flask_login.login_user(user, remember=True)
            return redirect(url_for('protected'))

    return jsonify(
        {"message": "authentication failed" }
    ), 401
```

The first call to `/api/login` works and 302 is returned correctly, but when it calls `/api/protected` (in the browser), it returns 400 BAD REQUEST instead of redirect to the specified location. How can I solve?

Comment: do you have a route '/site-to-interface.html'? I'm suspecting you might be trying to render that html (then use render_template). Note that redirect just serves to send the browser to a new address, not to serve html.

Comment: @GG_Python I have wirtten `site-to-interface.html` in the snippet, but in my code I have the redirect to another site: `return redirect('http://********.cs.unibo.it, code=302)`. I don't have templates. In practice I have the server executing in localhost, and i use ajax from that site to call the api in my localhost. I know that this isn't the best way to work, but it should work anyway